# How to fix 'jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time' or “The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.”in vscode?

Tags: kernel, jupyter

I am very new. I saw this question posted and I've tried all of the suggestions I could find. Even manually input the token for the port. Nothing worked.  Is there a definitive answer to this one yet?

Answer (score 0):

I now have a local Jupyter Server. But to be brutally honest i have no idea what worked.  I uninstalled everything and re-installed vs code, python packages and it just worked.